# Owl Carousel - Unconnected with Different Widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Here is my code:

### Here is the main SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
        items:11,
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:1000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        autoWidth:true
    });

});
```

### Here is the DIV:

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel" style="height:27px;">
  <div class="tag">1asfg</div>
  <div class="tag">2f</div>
  <div class="tag">3d34gs</div>
  <div class="tag">4barthrg</div>
  <div class="tag">5gef</div>
  <div class="tag">6gef</div>
  <div class="tag">7gef</div>
  <div class="tag">8gef</div>
  <div class="tag">9gef</div>
  <div class="tag">10gef</div>
  <div class="tag">11gef</div>
</div>
```

### Here are the style attributes of TAG:

```
<style>
    .tag {
        float:left;
        padding-bottom:2px;
        padding-right:5px;
        position:relative;
        background:#BFC9D9;
        width:auto;
        display:table;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:10px;
        text-align:center;
        border-top-right-radius:2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
        margin-top:3px;
        margin-bottom:3px;
    }
    .tag:after {
        right:100%;
        top:50%;
        border:solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height:0;
        width:0;
        position:absolute;
        border-right-color:#BFC9D9;
        border-width:10px;
        margin-top:-10px;
    }
</style>
```

I've got eleven items. Each item is of a different width. The items aren't seamless. That is, they don't loop in a perfectly connected congo. How can I change this?

Comment: Each `.owl-item` should have its width set in its own CSS. Other than that, it's hard to tell why yours wouldn't work right without seeing your actual layout code.

Comment: `autoWidth` is not an owl-carousel setting. The heights can be variable, but the slides need to be the same width as far as the docs would have us believe.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look good with same width... You see what I'm trying to create though, right?

Comment: Yes, but can't you find a way to allow the items to be tiled onto tiles the same size?

Comment: These blocks are calculated to be the right width: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autowidth.html

Comment: Lora, they have the widths set on them explicitly - on each block.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width explicitly on each block's style, they will render correctly:

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel" style="height:27px;">
  <div class="tag" style="width:100px">1asfg</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:150px">2f</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:100px">3d34gs</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:200px">4barthrg</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:150px">5gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:150px">6gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:100px">7gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:100px">8gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:250px">9gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:100px">10gef</div>
  <div class="tag" style="width:150px">11gef</div>
</div>
```

You should also be able to set the widths through css using ids or classes defining various widths.

You can use jQuery to set their width attributes like this:

```
$('.tag').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var disp = el.css("display");
    el.css("display","inline");
    el.width(el.width());
    el.css("display",disp);
});
```

but in order to get them to set properly, you'll need to set your divs first to display inline so that their native widths are the widths of their contents, since divs by default are as wide as their parents allow them to be.

Comment: But the widths need to be the same width as the tag... Automatically, the tag titles are coming from a database, and so I won't want hard code the widths for each tag...

Comment: I tried something like `<div class="tag item" style="width:auto;">1asfg</div>`, but same problem... No continuity...

Comment: Needs to be the same width as the text contained in it... *

Comment: Maybe I can use jQuery to get the tag's `.width()` value? How would I do that?